# How to edit the text of label

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript.Could anybody suggest me how to change the text of label in below code

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="radioabc">
           <input id="radioabc" type="radio" value="def" name="input_Radio">
           abc
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="radioxyz">
           <input id="radioxyz" type="radio" value="pqr" name="input_Radio">
           xyz
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change text 'abc' and text 'xyz' to other values.
My approch to change text 'abc' to 'tvr'.

I've tried:

```
$($(".col-sm-6").children()[0]).children().text("tvr");
```

then it also removes input field.whats wrong in my approach or please suggest some other approach.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: yes Riad,I am using jquery

Comment: see the `javascript` solution...provided...jquery is far more easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change text by Javascript:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('radio');//got all nodes in divs
divs[0].children[0].lastChild.data = "tvr"; // similar for second text...using divs[1]
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9odxadcp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and do it easily:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d6v9j55w/)

html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="radioabc">abc</label>
        <input id="radioabc" type="radio" value="def" name="input_Radio" />
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="radioxyz">
        xyz   
        </label>
        <input id="radioxyz" type="radio" value="pqr" name="input_Radio" />
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('label').on('click', function(){
    $(this).text('something else');
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: In my question format input is included in label. so please check once your answer.I am try to change text 'abc' like $($(".col-sm-6").children()[0]).children().text("vgh"); then it removes input field also.Whats the wrong in my method??